# Hibernate Search Tuple Queries

Tags: hibernate-search

I have an entity Message with a one-to-many relation to an entity Header. How can I create a tuple based search query like

```
(message.headerKey="foo" and message.headerValue="123") and 
(message.headerKey="bar" and message.headerValue="456")
```

My current logic would also match when I swap the header values in my search criteria

```
(message.headerKey="foo" and message.headerValue="456") and 
(message.headerKey="bar" and message.headerValue="123")
```

How can I do a tuple based query using the Hibernate Search API?

This is my Message Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MESSAGE")

@Indexed
public class MessageEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="message_timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column(name="payload")
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String payload;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "message")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<HeaderEntity> headers;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

This is my Header Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="HEADER")
public class HeaderEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="header_key")
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String headerKey;

    @Column(name="header_value")
    Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String headerValue;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="message_id")
    private MessageEntity message;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

This is my search logic:

```
public List<MessageEntity> search(Header[] headers) {

        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(mgr);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MessageEntity.class).get();
        TermMatchingContext onFieldKey = qb.keyword().onField("headers.headerKey");
        TermMatchingContext onFieldValue = qb.keyword().onField("headers.headerValue");

        BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> bool = qb.bool();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = null;
        for (Header header : headers) {
           bool.must(onFieldKey.matching(header.getKey()).createQuery());
           bool.must(onFieldValue.matching(header.getValue()).createQuery());
        }

        query = bool.createQuery();

        FullTextQuery persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, MessageEntity.class);

        persistenceQuery.setMaxResults(10);
        return persistenceQuery.getResultList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will indeed not work. The problem is that Lucene is a flat data structure, in particular associations (embedded entities) are just "added" to the Lucene `Document` of the owning entity. In your case the `MessageEntity` document will contain two fields per `headerKey` respectively `headerValue`. Once with "foo" and "bar" as value and56" as values.  once with "123" and "456" as values. There is no notion that two of these values are acutally a pair.

One potential solution is to create a unique field/value pair. Using a custom class bridge you could create a "keyValueField" containing header key and value as concatenated value. In your query you would then target this field using concatenated query parameters.